# Can't find variable itemData in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';

import GoalItem from './components/GoalItem';

export default function App() {
    const [enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal] = useState('');

    const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]);


    const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {

        setEnteredGoal(enteredText);
    };


    const addGoalHandler = () => {

        //console.log(enteredGoal);

        setCourseGoals(currentGoals => [...currentGoals, { id: Math.random().toString(), value: enteredGoal }]);
    };
    return (

        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>

                <TextInput placeholder="Course Goal" style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText={goalInputHandler} value={enteredGoal} />
                <Button title="Add" onPress={addGoalHandler} />

            </View>
            <FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id} data={courseGoals}
                renderItem={itemData => <GoalItem title={itemData.item.value} />}



            />


        </View>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    screen: {
        padding: 50
    },
    inputContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'

    },

    input: {

        width: '70%', borderBottomColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, padding: 10
    },

});
```

**GoalItem Components :**

```
import React from 'react';

import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const GoalItem = props => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.listItem}>
            <Text>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
    );


};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    listItem: {

        padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#ccc', borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, marginVertical: 10

    }


});
export default GoalItem;
```

> Error : Below is the code, please check Can't find variable itemData
>   in react-native

Pls i am a newbie in react-native i just got for about two hours. Any
help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Look into the code and share some advice so that the code works well..

Thanks :)

Comment: You'll get more help in the future if you properly format your posts

Comment: Pls help me i am just a newbie in react-native

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
<FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id} 
          data={courseGoals}
          renderItem={(itemData) => <GoalItem title={itemData.item.value} }/>
```

Or

```
<FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id} 
          data={courseGoals}
          renderItem={({item}) => <GoalItem title={item.value} }/>
```

Comment: thanks for the help the value is their but you did not see it:    value:enteredGoal.when i use your answer is still given me problem TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluting itemData.item)

Comment: If you are using 1st approach you can use `itemData.item`, but if you are using 2nd approach you can directly access `item`

Comment: the thing is still bringing error. i have make used of the first and second methods .syntaxError:jsx elements must be wrapped in an enclosed tag

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this :

```
<FlatList 
       data={courseGoals}
       renderItem={itemData => (
         
        <View  style={styles.listItem}>
          <Text>{itemData.item}</Text>
          </View>  
          )}
          />
```